# Call value in PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**class function**

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
        {
            if (is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }
```

**call method**

```
`$this->bind(":id","1","is_int");` 

//output = $this->stmt->bindValue(:id,1,is_int);
```

**Question**: How can i pass the value so that i can get the value to **$this->stmt->bindValue(":id","1",PDO::PARAM_INT);**

Comment: Its hard to tell from your code but if you extend the PDO class you extend it to something like `bindType(':key', 'value')` and it wouldn't need passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code. First, you're checking if `$type` is null with `is_null()`, which seems like the opposite of what you want, because the `switch` will only execute if `$type` is `NULL`, and if it is, none of the conditions will be satisfied. Further, that call is redundant since you still handle a `$type` of `NULL` in your `switch`.

Inside your `switch`, you call several different functions on `$type`, but none will get what you want. If you want to pass a string to indicate what kind of PARAM you need, do it like this:

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case "is_int":
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case "is_bool":
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case "is_null":
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
```

As a last comment, I'd set the `default` of the `switch` to `PDO::PARAM_NULL`, since that's the default value you use for the parameter in the function:

```
switch ($type) {
    case "is_int":
        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
    case "is_bool":
        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
    case "is_null":
        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        break;
    case "is_string":
        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        break;
    default:
        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
}
```